# Finding real and imaginary parts of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I split $w=e^z/z$ into its real and imaginary components?

Comment: Starting with $z:=\rho e^{i\phi}=\rho\cos(\phi)+i\rho\sin(\phi)\;$ may simplify somewhat...

Answer (score 1):

We know the real and imaginary components of the numerator and the denominator:

\begin{align}
e^{x + iy} & = e^{x} e^{iy} = e^x \cos y + i e^x \sin y
\end{align}
(where $ x, y \in \mathbb{R} $ - the denominator is split by definition) Combining this with the method of obtaining real and imaginary parts of a fraction:

\begin{align}
\frac{a + ib}{c + id} & = \frac{\left ( a + ib \right ) \left ( c - id \right )}{ \left ( c + id \right ) \left ( c - id \right )} = \frac{ac + bd}{c^2 + d^2} + i \frac{bc - ad}{c^2 + d^2} \;\;\;\;\;\;\; \text{(intended for $ a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R} $)}
\end{align}

should get you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
  \frac{e^{z}}{z} &= \frac{e^{x+yi}}{x+yi} \\
  &= \frac{e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)}{x+yi} \\
  &= \frac{e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)}{x+yi} \times \frac{x-yi}{x-yi} \\
  &= \frac{e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)(x-yi)}{x^2+y^2} \\
  &= \frac{e^{x}(x\cos y+y\sin y)}{x^2+y^2}+
     \frac{e^{x}(x\sin y-y\cos y)}{x^2+y^2}i
\end{align*}