# Compute $e^{e^z}$, where z is a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am self-studying the MAT 67 linear algebra course and I got stuck at a problem in Chapter 2:

> Compute the real and imaginary parts of $e^{e^z}$ for $z$ $\in$ $\Bbb C$.

I tried to expand it using Euler's formula but it seemed endless. Any help?

Comment: Find $u$ and $v$ for $e^{x+iy}=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ first. Then work on $e^{u+iv}$.

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1981065/finding-real-and-imaginary-parts-of-a-complex-function).

Answer (score 4):

> Let $z=x+iy\in\mathbb{C}$ with $x$ the real part and $y$ the imaginary part of $z$.
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \exp(e^{z})&=\exp(e^{x+iy})\\
> &=\exp({e^x}{e^{iy}})\\
> &=\exp({e^x}(\cos y+i\sin y))\\
> &=\exp({e^x}\cos y)\exp(ie^x\sin y))\\
> &=\exp({e^x}\cos y)(\cos(e^x\sin y)+i\sin(e^x\sin y))\\
> &=\cos(e^x\sin y)\exp({e^x}\cos y)+i\sin(e^x\sin y)\exp({e^x}\cos y)\\
> \end{align*}